# ? shows up on url for unknown reason after creating data on React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react.js for my frontend, right now working on one component. It is used to create a new data and display all data.

I am using
http://localhost:3000/locations
[screenshot before create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj1uf.png)

after creating data successfully, suddenly url becomes
http://localhost:3000/locations**?**
[screenshot after create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSDso.png)
I am wondering where is this ? question mark coming from, also I notice on my browser consolelog, the page is doing a fresh reload every time

I started the file with npx create-react-app, only modified App.js and Location.js

See App.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crw4X.png)

See code for Location.js

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from "axios"



export default function Location() {

    const [locations, setLocations] = useState([])
    const [locationname, setLocationname] = useState("")
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState("")
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState("")

    const createNewLocation = () => {
        const createLocation = async () => {
            const {data} = await axios.post("/api/locations", {locationname, coordinates: {latitude, longitude}} ,{headers: {"content-type": "application/json"}})
            console.log("data", data)
            setLocationname(locationname)
            setLatitude(latitude)
            setLongitude(longitude)
        }
        console.log("the click")
        createLocation()
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const getLocations = async() => {
            const {data} = await axios.get("/api/locations", {headers: {"content-type": "application/json"}})
            console.log(data)
            setLocations(data) 
        }
        getLocations()
    }, []) 

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={createNewLocation}>
                <label> locationname </label>
                <input type="text" value={locationname} onChange={(e)=>{setLocationname(e.target.value)}}/> <br></br>
                <label> latitude </label>
                <input type="text" value= {latitude} onChange={(e)=>{setLatitude(e.target.value)}}/> <br></br>
                <label> longitude </label>
                <input type="text" value= {longitude} onChange={(e)=>{setLongitude(e.target.value)}}/> <br></br>
                <button type="submit"> Add a new location </button>
            </form>
            
            <p> The current locations </p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Facility Name </th>
                    <th> Latitude </th>
                    <th> Longitude </th>
                </tr>
            {locations.map(
                location => 
                (<tr key={location.name}>  
                <td> {location.locationname} </td>
                <td> {location.coordinates.latitude} </td>
                <td> {location.coordinates.longitude} </td>
                </tr>)
            )}
            </table>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you aren't preventing the default of your form so it is still getting processed as a GET request.
If you had put values into the input fields you would of also seen those in your url.

Just include the event and prevent the default in your createNewLocation function

```js
    const createNewLocation = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Rest of your code
    }
```

Comment: Hello Richard, thanks a lot, really helpful.